# Lambda invoked by EventBridge - How to Unit Test with Go?

Tags: go

I have a go based Lambda that I'm writing, it's triggered by EventBridge and works fine but I want to add tests to my codebase.

I'm struggling to find how I can send a mock Eventbridge notification and examples are practically non-existant.

Using an example event from the [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-cloudwatchevents.html) I want to use this mock event and pass it to my handleRequest function and test that it handles it correctly.

What I don't understand is how to turn this mock event called dummyRequest into a events.CloudWatchEvent as defined in "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events" as my handleRequest function signature is "`func handleRequest(ctx context.Context, e events.CloudWatchEvent) (string, error)`"

lambda_test.go

```
package main

import (
    "testing"
)

func TestMain(t *testing.T) {

    dummyRequest := `{
        "version": "0",
        "id": "fe8d3c65-xmpl-c5c3-2c87-81584709a377",
        "detail-type": "RDS DB Instance Event",
        "source": "aws.rds",
        "account": "123456789012",
        "time": "2020-04-28T07:20:20Z",
        "region": "us-east-2",
        "resources": [
            "arn:aws:rds:us-east-2:123456789012:db:rdz6xmpliljlb1"
        ],
        "detail": {
            "EventCategories": [
                "backup"
            ],
            "SourceType": "DB_INSTANCE",
            "SourceArn": "arn:aws:rds:us-east-2:123456789012:db:rdz6xmpliljlb1",
            "Date": "2020-04-28T07:20:20.112Z",
            "Message": "Finished DB Instance backup",
            "SourceIdentifier": "rdz6xmpliljlb1"
        }
    }`

    handleRequest(nil, dummyRequest)
}
```

Comment: Use `json.Unmarshal` ?